# Push-Relabel maximum-flow algorithm in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm

How do I have to build the residual graph for Goldberg-Tarjan, if it has to be runnend on an undirected graph?
In a naive approach I would replace every undirected edge with two reverse directed edges, but the residual graph needs for every directed edge an backwards (residual) edge, so there would be four directed edges between every node, which seems wrong.

Descritpition of push-relabel algorithm in a lecture: https://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ws09_10/Opt2/handouts/lecture3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by "undirected graph" you mean that the capacities are the same in both directions between each pair of nodes - in other words, you have a *symmetric* (but directed) capacity graph - and that you don't want to think of the resulting flow to have a particular direction. A flow algorithm is inherently directed, but it will work just as well in a symmetric graph, and when you look at the resulting flow, you can choose to ignore its direction.

The only thing you need to realize is that there's really no distinction between a "forward" flow edge and a "reverse" flow edge: instead, there's one flow edge per capacity edge, and each flow edge is linked to the one in the opposite direction. This is also the case in your directed graphs, because not having an edge in a particular direction between a pair of nodes is the same as having an edge with capacity 0.

Whether your capacity graph is symmetric or not, you've always got a "negatively symmetric" flow graph: every pair of nodes has got two flow edges between them, and the flow in one direction must be the negative of the flow in the other direction. Increasing one must decrease the other, and decreasing one must increase the other. The positive flow can be in either direction as long as no capacity is being exceeded.

In a directed graph with a capacity of 5 and flow of 3 from A to B, there's a flow of -3 from B to A. The residual capacity from A to B is 2, and the residual capacity from B to A is 3 (original capacity of 0 minus flow of -3). In an "undirected" graph, the capacity from B to A would also be 5, which would give a residual capacity from B to A of 8 (original capacity of 5 minus flow of -3). If you now push 7 units of flow from B to A in the "undirected" graph, the flow from A to B is now -4 and the residual capacity is 9, and the flow from B to A is now 4 and the residual capacity is 1.